# How to refresh current page after ajax upload complete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, image-uploading

I'm working on [JS Ever](http://jsever.blogspot.com/) ajax multiple image uploader. It works really great but one thing. I need the working page reload after all file finish upload. Yes, there's a function to do something after a file uploaded like : **success**, **complete** or **done**. But these callback is per file. It's mean if I add a reload function to it. The page will be reloaded right after the first file is finished upload.

I've tried.

```
complete:function(file,xhr){alert("ok")}
```

It works! But it's 3 ok popups since I uploaded 3 files. I need only one "OK" alert after the 3rd file is upload. Please suggest.

```
$('#uploader').JSAjaxFileUploader({
    uploadUrl: 'upload.php',
    complete: function (file, xhr) {
        $(alert("ok"));
    }
});
```

[This is the DEMO.](http://jsfiddle.net/nobuts/y68zkup0/)

Comment: Looks like the plugin you are using doesn't provide enaugh information to do that. It would be nice if it had a callback for all uploads complete, but it doesn't (i looked at the source). `complete()` is indeed referring to to a single file upload and there is no easy way to get the amount of total requested file uploads (not without editing the source of the plugin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just add a count?

```
var count = 0;
var length;

$('#uploader').JSAjaxFileUploader({
  uploadUrl: 'upload.php',
  complete: function (file, xhr) { 
    if ( count === 0 ) {
      length = $('.JSpreveiw li').length;
    }      
    if ( count === length - 1 ) {
      alert('thanks for uploading!');
      window.location.reload();
    }
    count += 1;
  } 
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your script is work! But I adapt the structure to the original script. Otherwise the upload button disappeared : http://jsfiddle.net/nobuts/y68zkup0/5/ (It might not work here but it's perfect with my script)

Answer (score 0):

If there is a possibility to get the amount of files uploaded, you can make a function in your "complete" callback which increments a number. When that number equals your amount of files, show the alert and refresh the page.

Comment: I looked at the source and there is nothing like that exposed in the plugins API.

Comment: @Wilf according to bwitkowicz it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Use a hidden field on the page like `<input type="hidden" id="hidUploadCount" value="0" />`
Now use function **beforesend** to track current uploads. And use complete function to reload page if the count is upload in progress is 0 i.e.

```
$('#uploader').JSAjaxFileUploader({
  uploadUrl: 'upload.php',
  beforesend:function(){       
    document.getElementById('hidUploadCount').value+=document.getElementById('hidUploadCount').value;
  },
  complete: function (file, xhr) {
     document.getElementById('hidUploadCount').value-=document.getElementById('hidUploadCount').value;
  if(document.getElementById('hidUploadCount').value)==0)
  {
    alert("ok");//here u can reload the page
  }
  }
});
```

Comment: I've tried but no luck. According to the examples here : http://jseverdemo.0fees.net/JSAjaxFileUploader/Demo.html#div8. The callback is a per file action. Do you think it's possible to succeed it?

Comment: Yeah I saw your provided link and it says the same what I put above as the answer. See the logic is simple. Lets say you have 3 files to upload. So `beforesend` will execute 3 times and then `complete` will execute 3 times. If you increment a variable's value every time `beforesend` is called and then decrease it when `complete` is called, for the third file, it's value will become 3-3=0. You have to reload the page if it's value is 0. Getting my point.

Comment: You should actually try to `alert(document.getElementById('hidUploadCount').value)` every time to know what is actually happening there. This will give you more clear picture. You can also use a global variable instead of a hidden field.